# Converting adjacent values inside a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently working on an assignment where I have to read through, an already declared 2d array, and change the "colors" of the 0s adjacent to the colors that are up, down, right or to the left of them.

I am trying to loop through a character array printing it out with the ascii numbers first, then change all the 0s adjacent to the colors to the same "color"
for example
if I had something like

```
 1000
 G001
 1010
```

putting it through my program would have it end up like this

```
   1GGG
   GGG1
   1G10
```

I have it looping through twice, first shows the array without the values changed. And the second, is supposed to, change it into something like I have shown in my example.

This is what I have come up with thus far

```
public class MatrixTest{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {int[][] array = {{1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                 {1,1,1,1,'G',0,0},
                 {0,0,'B',0,1,0,1},
                 {1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                 {1,0,1,'R',1,0,1},
                 {1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
                 {0,0,0,1,1,1,1},
                 {0,'B',0,1,0,'G',0}};  

    for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 7; col++)
        {
        System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");

        }System.out.println();  
    }

    System.out.println("\n\n" + "Output: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            if(array[i][j] != 0 && array[i][j] != 1){
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            }//Here I would like to say something like if(array[i+1][j] == 0) change color
             //and do so for the other cases as well, i-1, j+1, j-1... doesn't move diagonally
            if(array[i][j] == 1)
                System.out.print(1 + "");

        }System.out.println();

    }
}
```

}
`

So far the second pair of loops only show the 1s and colors, if I added in the 0s the same way I did the 1s it would just be the same as the first array, which would be pointless to have printed out again. Once all the 0s that are adjacent to the colors have been changed I could just convert them to their relative ascii value.

I would like to change the colors inside the first if statement, but I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let you know, you are going to have to build the new 2d array before you print out the answer. Currently you are trying to print out the answer as you go through the array but in your example output at the top the 0 in the first row second coulomb was not adjacent to any colors which means that a 0 that changes to a color can change other 0s to that same color. This makes printing out the answer as you build the new 2d array difficult. If I were doing this assignment I would build a recursive function that would change all of the 0s with adjacent colors to those colors and if a any 0s got changed after the loop you would call the function again. Something like:

```
function declaration(array){
    int colorChanged = 0;
    for row{
        for coulomb{
            if (color adjacent){change color; colorChanged = 1;}
        }
    }
    if (colorChanged == 1){function(array)}
    return array
}
```

Note that this is just an example and not working code but hopefully it should give you some ideas.